# PowerBI Calculated Column Troubleshooting

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax

I am relatively new to PowerBI, but I have been a long time SQL user.

I currently have a DataWarehouse running on SQL Server 2016 fronted by SSAS. As I go through the process of populating measures/calculated columns in SSAS to be consumed by PowerBI, I have run into a similar problem time and time again.

It seems like troubleshooting DAX for a calculated column is full of trial and effort. Is there a better way of "testing" DAX rather than just plugging it into SSAS, and seeing if it works in PBI? I have tried DAX Studio, but it seems to be not super compatible with a Calculated Column version of DAX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What are the issues that you faced with DAX Studio? You can use the DEFINE COLUMN syntax in DAX Studio to create query columns that persists only for the duration of the session.

```
DEFINE COLUMN Table[Column] = 
    "tscrip"
EVALUATE
    Table
```